# Laravel selectively use plugins from node modules

Tags: javascript, laravel, node-modules

I am working on laravel with admin lte3. I use the datatables plugin from adminlte 3 in few specific views.

I achieved it by adding it into `resources/js/bootstrap.js`.

```
require('bootstrap');
require('admin-lte');
require("admin-lte/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables");
```

this works fine.

The only issue is that I have many other views where this datatables are not used and I don't want to add this entire plugin that is going to be used for one view into all the views. That is clearly unnecessary loading of js which won't be used.

Is there a way I can selectively add this plugin located in

```
node_modules/adminlte3/plugins/datatables
```

specifically to certain views in their `@section(custom-js) HERE SHOULD BE IMPORT STATEMENT      @endsection` section so that it will be loaded after following code in the mail layout view.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
@yield('custom-js')
```

via `@yield('custom-js')` statement.

my views are structured like this

```
@section('content')
HTML PORTION OF THE VIEW
@endsection
@section('custom-js')
IF ANY JS SPECIFIC TO THAT VIEW
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Laravel Mix?

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix

However, i think it is ok to just load it in the main template layout.
Javascript (and other assets) are cached by web browsers by default and most people doesn't disable this browser cache.